# Setting up ArcGIS Viewer for Flex?

Tags: installation, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am still a newbie at the Flex Viewer; I have been using the Out of the Box Web Application for Server 10.0.

I tried to put a simple service as an additional basemap (I also tried it as an additional operational layer) and now the viewer will not fully open up.

After I refresh the page multiple times it finally comes up but doesn't work properly.

The map service I have added is not cached but I don't cache it for the Out of the box web application.

The map service is relatively small geographically, and currently has no large feature classes in it or imagery. Would caching the map service change it that much??

I'd like to add imagery into but I want to get it working without it first. I would like to replace the web mapping application with the Flex viewer as there are more options.

The data server and the web server are on the same machine. The map service is also using UNC paths as I am creating the original map on a different machine but if that is huge problem that could be adjusted.

Trouble is the machine that has ArcGIS Server on it does not have Desktop and vice versa. Kind of limited with a single use license.

Answer (score 4):

Flex 2.2 is just out. It is very easy to add the flex sample application and get it going. You should find plenty here... [Flex 2.2](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/help/index.html#whats_new.htm)

Comment: Yeah, I actually have 2.2, thought that would help me.  I guess what I will do is set the map to all mapped drives and cache the map accordingly and see what happens with it.  It also doesn't help that my basemap is in State Plane so I can't leave the other base maps on.

Comment: are you having a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is your old (e.g. ADF "out of the box") viewer using an **ArcGIS Server Local** or **ArcGIS Server Internet** connection?

The Flex viewer will only use an Internet connection.  If ArcGIS Server is having trouble generating images via an Internet connection but not via a Local connection then that is your problem; nothing to do with the caching.

Caching your map may bypass your problem but should not be a necessary step to getting the Flex viewer working.